# Python pandas explode on multiple columns in a Cartesian manner

Tags: pandas, explode

I have a dataframe with some columns that are lists. I want to explode the columns but in stead of one-to-one, I want Cartesian (multiplicative) rows to be generated.

Does it have to go thru a for loop or something elegant is possible?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[0, 1],5],
                   'B': 1,
                   'C': [['a', 'b'], 'phau']})

df.explode(['A','C'])


#Default output

   A  B     C
0  0  1     a
0  1  1     b
1  5  1  phau

#Desired output
   A  B     C
0  0  1     a
0  0  1     b
0  1  1     a
0  1  1     b
1  5  1  phau
```

Comment: `df.explode('A').explode('C')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_1 = df.explode('A').explode('C')
```

Comment: Just checking how answering own question behave.

Comment: You shouldn't copy and paste the other answer, and then mark yours as accepted if theirs solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.explode('A').explode('C')
```